# Unzip signature not found

Tags: linux, tar, unzip, spam-prevention, phpbb

I tried to unzip  https://github.com/CleanTalk/phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam/releases/tag/5.7.2
on debian 10 vps machine or linux Mint but It always returns the same error:

```
unzip phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam-5.7.2.zip
```

> Archive:  phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam-5.7.2.zip
>     End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
>     a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
>     latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
>     the last disk(s) of this archive.
>     unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam-5.7.2.zip or
>     phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam-5.7.2.zip.zip, and cannot find phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam-5.7.2.zip.ZIP, 
>     period.

unzip -v is 6.0 Compiled with gcc 8.3.0 for Unix (Linux ELF)

tarball version :

```
tar -xvf phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam-5.7.2.tar.gz
```

> tar: This does not look like a tar archive
>   gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
>   tar: Child returned status 1
>   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: What URL you used? Correct link is https://github.com/CleanTalk/phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam/archive/5.7.2.tar.gz

Comment: this https://github.com/CleanTalk/phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam/releases/tag/5.7.2 (release) but your file linked returns the same error. I discovered that I can only unzip it  with archive manager for gnome ( linux mint 19.3)   ... I cant on terminal

Comment: tar -xvf phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam-5.7.2.tar.gz
tar: This does not look like a tar archive

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Try running `file phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam-5.7.2.tar.gz` against the file you've download. That will tell you what it is.

Comment: `$ tar xvf phpbb3.1-3.2-antispam-5.7.2.tar.gz` works perfectly OK here.